# リスト内包表記を使わずに書くなら

Tags: haskell

```
hoge n = [(x,y) | x <- [-n .. n], y <- [-n .. n]]
```

この関数をリスト内包表記を使わずに書くなら、どう書けますか？

Answer (score 6):

リストをアプリカティブとして使うなら

```
hoge n = (\x y -> (x,y)) <$> [-n .. n] <*> [-n .. n]
```

モナドとして使うなら

```
hoge n = do x <- [-n .. n]
            y <- [-n .. n]
            return (x,y)
```

と書けます。